# What does scim multi-tenant mean?

Tags: azure-active-directory, okta, scim, scim2

Can anyone please confirm what a `tenant` means from SCIM RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644.html#section-6?

If resources (i.e users/groups) synced from client (i.e, Azure AD or Okta) can also be accessible or in-accessible by other clients, then does it means multi-tenant scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a SaaS service provider like Dropbox - where the SaaS provider may host hundreds or thousands of separate environments, typically broken by customer/organizational boundaries. That is what multi-tenancy means in this context.

Comment: Thank you. 

Do you if it is possible to manage users in different tenants using one client? For example, one Azure AD syncs users to different environments in Dropbox?

Comment: Yes - in Azure AD this would typically be via multiple provisioning jobs configured, with each job pointing to a separate SCIM app tenant. This is typically specified either by a value in the bearer/oauth token that indicates the target environment, or via a URL (i.e.: rather than api.whatever.com/scim, it could be api.whatever.com/directoryId/scim)